# Issue on Using Regular Expression in PHP Simple Validation

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to learn Regular Expression in PHP by creating simple samples.Here I have very simple example as:

```
if($_POST){
   $errors = array();

  if(isset($_POST['name'])){
     if(!preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]{3,8})$/',$_POST['name'])){
       $errors['name1'] = "Must enter Alphabet";
       $errors['name2'] = ""Cant be less than 3";
     }

  }
  if(count($errors)==0){
  header("Location: pro.php");
  exit();
  }
}
?>

<form method="POST" target="">
First name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

To me, the validation is working fine but I have problem on presenting error message based on error.For example I would like to display error `$errors['name1']` ONLY when not string has entered and `$errors['name2']` while numbers entered.
I tried to separate expression into two criteria as:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
   {
     if(!preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z])$/',$_POST['name']))
     {
       $errors['name1'] = "Must enter Alphabet";
     }
      if(preg_match('/^{3,8}$/',$_POST['name']))
     {
       $errors['name2'] = "Cant be less than 3";
     }
   }
```

but I am getting following error 
[image]

**Update**

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
   {
     if(!preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z])$/',$_POST['name']))
     {
       $errors['name1'] = "Must enter Alphabet";
     }
      if ( ! preg_match( '/.{3,8}/', $_POST['name'] ))
     {
       $errors['name2'] = "Cant be less than 3";
     }
   }
```

Comment: I do realize that you're trying to learn and practice regular expressions but I just thought I'd point out these two functions for reference, since they are more efficient than using regular expressions: [`ctype_alpha`](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) and [`mb_strlen`](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php). Good luck with the regex though!

Comment: Thanks rink, they were helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am going to answer my question.Thanks to [Masud Alam](http://www.w3programmers.com/working-with-php-regular-expression/) I figure it out how to do this in Regular Expression. The hint is using

```
 if (!preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', $_POST['name'])) {
     //
 }

 if (!preg_match('/^.{3,25}$/', $_POST['name'])) {
     //
 }
```

it works for me so far!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is the result of not specifying match criteria in the regex before the {} operator. If you only care whether at least three of ANY character had been entered, try

```
if ( ! preg_match( '/.{3,8}/', $haystack ) )
```

You have to provide an 'atom' for the range to count. In this case, '.' signifies any single character.

Comment: Hi Tarnation, Thanks for your comment, I updated the code as above and based on your hint I am not getting any error message now but it seems the validation is not working as it is not processing even the correct enteries

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    if (preg_match('/[^a-z])/i', $_POST['name'])) {
        $errors['name1'] = "Must enter Alphabet";
    }
    if ( strlen($_POST['name']) < 3) {
        $errors['name2'] = "Cant be less than 3";
    }
    if ( strlen($_POST['name']) > 8) {
        $errors['name3'] = "Cant be more than 8";
    }
}
```

If you really want to use regex:

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-z])/i', $_POST['name'])) {
    $errors['name1'] = "Must enter Alphabet";
}
if ( ! preg_match('/^.{3,8}$/', $_POST['name']) ) {
    $errors['name2'] = "Cant be less than 3";
}
```

Comment: Thanks M42, but I was looking for same function in Regular Expression format.instead of having two srtlen()