# Validating user input with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I wish to implement regular expressions as a way to check user input and after reviewing this post ([Issue on Using Regular Expression in PHP Simple Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524421/issue-on-using-regular-expression-in-php-simple-validation)) i came up with code below. When i run my script, and input numbers for first and last names, they get posted successfully regardless of my regex . I was wondering what i may be doing wrong here.

```
<?php
$errors = array();
// ....create database connection.....//
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {

$last_name = trim($_POST['last_name']);
$first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
$age = trim($_POST['age']);

// ....My regular expressions.....//
 if(isset($_POST['last_name'])){
 if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST['last_name']) === 0) {
  $errors[] = 'lastname should not contain spaces.'; }
  }

if(isset($_POST['first_name'])){
if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST['first_name']) === 0) {
  $errors[] = 'firstname should not contain spaces.';} 
}
  $OK = false;
   $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO voter_tracking (
        v_id,
        last_name,
        first_name,)
    VALUES(?, ?,?)';
  if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
     $stmt->bind_param('iss', $_POST['v_id'], $_POST['last_name'],        $_POST['first_name']);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
  $OK = true;
}
       // redirect if successful or display error
       if ($OK) {
    echo 'posted';
    exit;
   } else {
    $error = $stmt->error;
   }}}
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Home</title>
 </head>

 <body>
<div id="main">
    <fieldset>
            <legend><h2>Add New Voter Record:</h2></legend>
            <?php if (isset($error)) {
              echo "<p class=\"warning\">Error: $error</p>";
            } ?>
            <form id="form1" method="post" action="">             
          <p>
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" class="widebox" id="name" required aria-required="true">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="widebox" id="first_name" required aria-required="true">
          </p>

          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert New Entry" id="insert">
          </p>

        </form>
        </fieldset>          
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My first question: do you even understand what the regex does? Can you read it? Can you maintain it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the opener must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem to be solved

Comment: Looks like. He just copied that code but cant read it. My advice: Use easier methods which are understandable for beginners, best thing would be the string functions. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php If you dont know how to handle Regex, its senseless to give you any advices about it. Every experienced RegExer sees the mistake, but if you cant see it on your own, youll never learn.

Comment: @hek2mgl, this close reason was removed from the list close reasons list. I think, adding it now in the "others" section is not what was expected.

Comment: @stema Oh! I didn't knew that, thx

Comment: @hek2mgl, there has been some discussion on meta [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215546#215546) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215587/close-reasons-cheat-sheet/215622#comment696726_215622) (it is quite a lot to read :( )

Comment: Try to create a minimum example and use code indentation properly, it is very hard to see what belongs together in your code. Your regex does not look too bad, but I am not sure about the logic. But I and I think most of the others here too, have not the time to clean up your code and to debug it.

Comment: Can you give some examples of valid and invalid input?

Comment: Why can't the first name have spaces?  Do you not want Mary Ann Summers to use your site?  Why can't the last name have spaces?  Do you not want Eddie Van Halen to use your site?

Comment: Thank you @Andy Lester for the observation, I was basically testing the regex logic at this point, i have sorted that out based on the solution proposed by MElliott. I have also sorted out the appropriate regex syntax for my different data fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex appears to be ok.

Your problem is that you need to check for errors before posting/inserting into database..  Something like this:

```
if (count($errors) > 0) {
   // prepare and execute sql insert here.
}
```

Comment: @Y U NO WORK,@MElliott  Thank you, that was the missing link in my understanding of the implementation logic of regex, i implemented this 
    if(empty($reg_errors))
    { // prepare and execute sql insert here.} to check for errors before posting and my validation system is working as expected.

Comment: @MichelMzer - Excellent!  Glad I could help!  If you found this as the answer or was helpful to solve your problem, please accept as answer or upvote it or both, thank you.  :)